# Harmful effects from LEDs exploding

Tags: led

So, I've hooked up 2 leds to a 3.3v rail on my breadboard and they both exploded, Does anyone know the effects of the smoke that comes out of them? I think I inhaled some of it.

Comment: To be honest, I think this is more relevant to http://health.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Red/orange/yellow LEDs might be made of gallium arsenide phosphide. Do you happen to have a datasheet?

Comment: If you can answer this question, you can probably also answer [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/248568/what-material-is-used-in-the-common-5mm-led) question.

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert, but my guess is that most, if not all, of the smoke was created by the burning plastic lens, and not from the semiconductor materials (the "rock") that constitutes the LED. I mean, consider the vaporization temperatures for the semiconductor materials versus the smoke point temperature of the plastic lens. It seems unlikely to me that the semiconductor materials got so hot that they not only melted but actually boiled to the gaseous state or burned. The plastic lens, on the other hand, could easily burn and produce smoke due to the flash of heat produced by a catastrophic failure of this sort. Specifically, the heat probably melted the plastic above the die, boiled/burned the plastic, and the rapid expansion of trapped gasses above the die caused the plastic lens to explode. (If any experts out there can refute this assertion, please do.) FWIW, the manufacturer might publish a material safety data sheet for the LED that identifies known health hazzards.

Comment: The plastic is usually epoxy resin. There's lots of info on the hazards of *uncured* resin, but not on burning the finished product. At a guess I'd say it's mildly carcinogenic, but the quantity is so tiny that it's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs don't contain any gases. It is probably the smoke due to the burning of silicon wafer or something like that. Wouldn't say that will intoxicate you :). You should use a resistor there.

Comment: would a resistor slow down the inhalation of smoke :p

Comment: would it? That could prevent the accident :p

Comment: Proper use of resistors can prevent the accidental release of the magic smoke that makes electronics work.

Comment: Use a 100R resistor on a 3.3v rail and there should be no burnout.